# Slow enum parsing when debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, enums

I have `(T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), inputValue, true);` in my extension method to help parsing strings into enums. While this works well and as expected it is utterly slow when debugging. Same situation with generic version of this method: `Enum.Parse<MyEnum>(inputValue, true);`. When running without debugger attached (Ctrl+F5) all works normally. Is it Visual Studio's issue or there is a reason why it must be so slow?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "when debugging"? You assume these instructions cause the debugger to be slow? If so, why particularly? Or do you have any conditional breakpoints associated with such an expression? Conditional breakpoints are slow, but that would not be related to the code you debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad. I found the problem and it wasn't directly caused by `Enum.Parse()`. My code is reading txt file with ~1000+ lines that contain values I want to parse into enums. When it fails it catches exception and THIS takes about 15ms to process - only when running with debugger attached.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)